# Run Service When The File / Folder Is Modified

Tags: windows-7, services

I want to know if there is a possibility to trigger a service when a folder or file changed.

I found sc triggerinfo but I don't know if I can use it for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possibly in several ways, for example [with Power Shell Script](http://dereknewton.com/2011/05/monitoring-file-system-changes-with-powershell/):

There are several strategies that you can use to monitor the file system in PowerShell:

- Create a new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher object, and set appropriate settings:

  ```
  $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
  $watcher.Path = $searchPath
  $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
  ```

  .Path is the path that will be monitored, .IncludeSubdirectories tells the FileSystemWatcher to monitor all subdirectories of .Path
- Now we need to define some events that will fire when $watcher detects a filesystem change, I’m going to define an event for Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed:

> ```
> $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
>    write-host "Changed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
> }
> $created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
>    write-host "Created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
> }
> $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action {
>    write-host "Deleted: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
> }
> $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action {
>    write-host "Renamed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
> }
> ```

- Within each event you can define code for what you want to happen when the event fires.  In this example I’m just directly outputting the type of action and the full path of the changed object on the filesystem.
- That’s pretty much it.  These events will hang around until you close your current PowerShell session or manually unregister the events.  You can unregister the events using the Unregister-Event command:

  ```
  Unregister-Event $changed.Id
  Unregister-Event $created.Id
  Unregister-Event $deleted.Id
  Unregister-Event $renamed.Id
  ```

Comment: I can't use PowerShell (it's for work). But I'm using a similar solution, with python.

My basic idea it's a native way using directly win services events handler (as we can use for launch at login of an user)

But I keep your answer, it will be usefull ^^ Thanks !